# Prove that the angles are equal

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to prove this question using mid point theorem.

I did by joining the points X Y and Z. But my method is long. So is there any other way to do this using mid point theorem?[image][image]

Comment: You should include your method, even if it is long. There could be easy-to-spot ways to simplify it. Also, how will anyone know that their method is different than yours if you don't show yours? In general, showing as much as you know about a problem helps people avoid wasting time (theirs and yours) telling you things you already know, duplicating your effort, or using techniques with which you aren't yet familiar. Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3289849/edit) with any clarifications; comments are often overlooked.

Comment: I have attached the way i did. Can u please check and tell me whether there is a shorter method than this?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct; the proof is long only because you repeated yourself unnecessarily. You can simplify the argument with a little bit of focus; mention only what you need from the Midpoint Theorem for the task at hand. (For part (i), you only need parallelism; for part (ii), you need the half-length property.) Also, make liberal use of "likewise". :)

For instance, for (i), you can write simply ...

- In $\triangle ABP$: $\;\overline{ZX}\parallel\overline{AB}$ (Midpt Thm), so $\angle BAP\cong\angle XZP$ (Corresp $\angle$s).
- *Likewise*, in $\triangle APC$: $\;\angle CAP\cong \angle YZP$.
- Therefore, $\angle BAC \cong \angle XZY$ (Angle Addition Axiom).
- *Likewise*, $\angle ACB\cong\angle ZYX$ and $\angle ABC\cong \angle YXZ$.

For (ii), you can start ...

- In $\triangle ABP$: $\;|ZX| = \frac12|AB|$ (Midpt Thm) ... (but phrasing this as "$|AB|=2|ZX|$" is a little better, considering the way the problem is stated).
- *Likewise*, in $\triangle BCP$ and $\triangle CAP$: ...
- Therefore, ...

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, i got you. Thank you soo much, it was very helpfull..:))

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you connect midpoints of two sides of a triangle the resulting segment is parallel to the third side and its length is half the length of the third side.

In your question both parts are the immediate consequences of the above statement.